# Error creating Connection: Resource already exists - apply blocked by lifecycle params pulumi connection

Tags: python, github, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I am connecting repositories to google cloud build. and the first step is adding a connection. A team-mate has already added the connection before. but when working on my stack I cant access is anymore. meaning that pulumi up now results in the following error

`Error creating Connection: Resource already exists - apply blocked by lifecycle params:`

I have even tried import but It gives another error.